# pdf2docx is not able to join tables that span across two pages

Tags: python, pypdf

I have quite simple code:

```
def pdf_to_docx(pdf_file, docx_file):
    try:
        cv = Converter(pdf_file)
        tables = cv.extract_tables()
        cv.close()
        doc = Document()
        for table in tables:
           #do stuff
```

However, I have a table which spans across two pages, when I look into 'Tables' it shows this Table as 2 different ones.

The issue I face is that because I don't have the header on the second page, my code cannot work out how to join them together.

Any idea how I can resolve this or how to join them up easily?

My end goal is to convert all tables in a PDF into Excel (i have to convert to word as some files I use are word and others are PDFs.

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't extract header from first table and save it to memory and then create a new table in code with first header and join all other table values in a for loop?

Comment: @RezaAkraminejad I have around 40 tables. Some go across two pages, others dont. It wouldn't work unfortunately

Comment: So if you want to do it just for tables which goes across two pages, you need to save every table header in temp and save it until new table will have another header, every time you reach a table without headers, you will result that this one goes across two pages, so you will join records as one tables. Also you need a variable as a temp tables for saving record. It needs a little programming but not so hard. Good luck.

Comment: @RezaAkraminejad thanks! But some tables only have two columns and others have 5, how would I know if that if a table has a header or not?

Comment: There is no difference between headers and values in library that you use to extract tables? Does it have this feature? If does not, how do you identify headers in you code?

Comment: Usually if it is 3 columns or more, it will have headers. if it is just 2, then it wont

Comment: So you have to do it based on this condition if your library can not identify headers. If your program just want to export a few multiple column, do it in this way, on the other hand for many documents that will be analyzed dynamically everyday, you can not trust in this method.

Comment: Just to be clear here, you seem to be talking about https://github.com/dothinking/pdf2docx - It seems to be hardcoded into the library to parse each page separately: https://github.com/dothinking/pdf2docx/blob/master/pdf2docx/converter.py#L376 - Is it possible for you to share an example PDF that displays the issue?

Comment: @jqurious sorry for slow reply. Yep, it is that one. Are you saying that it should carry it forward then?

Comment: Well no, it's a design choice. It's "easy" to answer the question "Is there a table on this page?" - It's much harder (impossible in some cases?) to answer the question "Does this table start on a previous page?" - In this case, it looks like you would have to write your own version of  `cv.extract_tables()`

Comment: In word it continues over